# How can two android devices know the presence of each other

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I'm developing an andoird application that needs to know how many and what kind of other android devices are using the same application. After digging about BLE and Wifi Direct, I'm doubt that there is no efficient way to do so, since BLE API in android can't advertise a device and Wifi Direct will prevent the device from connecting to Wifi routers.

My requirements are it should be done power efficiently and cause minimal impact on normal network usage for users.

Comment: Do you need to discover *every* Android device, or would it be acceptable to have an app installed on the other devices to allow the discovery ?

Comment: "[...] since BLE API in android can't advertise a device". I think since Lollipop (API 21), this support has been introduced.

Comment: @HalimQarroum, it is acceptable to have an app installed

Comment: Thanks @Santa, you are right. API21 provides the API to let android device act as _peripheral_ device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be using the [Nsd (Network Service Discovery)](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) APIs provided by the Android SDK.

This will use under the hood multicast DNS to perform the discovery of remote services on the local area network. You will have to build an advertisement application to be installed on a remote device, and have your client app discover the remote device.

You might want to take a look at the [NsdManager class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdManager.html) which provides useful pieces of informations about how the API is working.

Comment: So it seems to use Wifi and won't work in a environment without Wifi access?

Comment: I think this is the best I could do with so far, thanks!